# How to use Scala format and substitution interpolation together?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foreach, rdd, scala-ide

I am new to scala and spark and have a requirement where i want to use both format and substitution in a single println statement.

Here is the code:

```
val results = minTempRdd.collect()

for(result <- results.sorted){
  val station = result._1
  val temp = result._2
  println(f" StId $station Temp $temp%.2f F")
}
```

where results is an RDD having structure (stationId, Temperature).

Now i want to convert this code into one liner. I tried the following code:

```
val results = minTempRdd.collect()

results.foreach(x => println(" stId "+x._1+" temp = "+x._2))
```

It works fine, but i am not able to format the second value in tuple here.

Any suggestions, how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first way is to use curly brackets inside interpolation, which allow to pass arbitrary expressions instead of variables:

```
println(f" StId ${result._1} Temp ${result._2}%.2fF")
```

The second way is to unpack the tuple:

```
for ((station, temp) <- results.sorted) 
  println(f" StId $station Temp $temp%.2fF")
```

Or:

```
results.sorted.foreach { case (station, temp) => 
  println(" stId "+x._1+" temp = "+x._2) 
}
```

Comment: println(f" StId ${result._1} Temp ${result._2}%.2fF") This is what i was looking for...Thanks :)